# Update integer values every second in Java with something between the given numbers

Tags: java, graphics, integer

I have 2 integer values, let's say int a = 5 and int b = 4.

```java
public static void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;//60 times per second
    double delta = 0;
    
    while(running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta = delta + ((now-lastTime) / ns);
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1)//Make sure update is only happening 60 times a second
        {
            
            delta--;
        }
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to change values of the integers within the `while (delta >= 1){}`  every second to a number between 100 and 400. I want to create a paint method that takes the values of the integers and updates the component sizes within my JFrame. I just need an idea to go with, so I can move on.

Comment: What is the value of running ? Where are you declaring a and b... not sure I am able understand your concern

Comment: Running is equal to true, i just wrote an idea at the top of the code block so you know what i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question. However, if your intention is to run a bit of code 60 times per second, there is definitely an easier way to accomplish this - via Java's `Thread.sleep()` mechanism. You can use Java's `Random` class to actually generate random values for `a` and `b`:

```
    public static void run() {
        Random random = new Random();

        while (running) {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(16); // 16 millisecond sleep; will run 60 times per second

                // Generate random number between 100 and 400
                a = (random.nextInt() % 300) + 100;
                b = (random.nextInt() % 300) + 100;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception encountered when trying to sleep! " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can also use Java's `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes to the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! I actually wanted to ask how to even do this but i remembered i've had a game with this method and just decided to post that.  This is so much more readable and better!